# Смена при каждом обновлении страницы изображений между собой по кругу

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть три картинки:

```
    <img class="anim1" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u1.gif">
    <img class="anim2" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u2.gif">
    <img class="anim3" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u3.gif">
```

Мне надо, что бы после каждого обновления страницы картинки менялись между собой по кругу местами, а не рандомно. Пример.

После первой перезагрузки

```
   <img class="anim2" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u2.gif">
   <img class="anim3" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u3.gif">
   <img class="anim1" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u1.gif">
```

После второй перезагрузки

```
   <img class="anim3" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u3.gif">    
   <img class="anim1" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u1.gif">
   <img class="anim2" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u2.gif">
```

После третей вернулось на исходную

```
   <img class="anim1" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u1.gif">
   <img class="anim2" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u2.gif">
   <img class="anim3" src="http://s2.uploads.ru/u3.gif">
```

Как можно такое реализовать?

Comment: создай массив этих самых картинок, сохрани в `localStorage` индекс той самой картинки, и уже по условию какая была картинка пред идущая, после загрузки измени индекс при загрузке

Comment: А можно на примере если не сложно .

Answer (score 2):

Тут пример не будет работать. Снипет не поддерживает `localStorage`;

```js
let image = [
  'https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/158/354748-admin_3840x2400.jpg',
  'http://wnature.net/pictures/2015/06/2311/leopard-v-moment-bega.jpg',
  'https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/260/289492-alexfas01.jpg'
];
document.querySelector('img').src = image[0];
window.onload = function() {
  let count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('index'));
  document.querySelector('img').src = image[count];
  if (parseInt(count) < (image.length - 1)) {
    localStorage.setItem('index', count + 1);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('index', 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="foto" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно. Но я имел не много не то в веду. Мне надо что бы картинки все три менялись местами не по принципу ротатора, а друг за другом.

Comment: Вопрос надо оформлять так, чтобы было понятно... А из того, что было в описании, я понял так,  как реализовал)))

Comment: Извините за неточность. Поправил вопрос в шапке.